# BAR 6, no space for memory

Tags: boot, 16.04, kernel, memory-usage

I have been trying to trouble shoot a PCIe card that is preventing my server from booting. Looking at the syslogs I noticed an entry:

`Mar 31 12:56:52 ubuntu kernel: [    0.856793] pci 0000:02:00.0: BAR 6: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 pref]`

I have tried to find information about BAR 6 but wasn't able to come up with anything. Anybody have any ideas?